# Understanding Delegate flow

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, delegates, tcplistener

First, I want to apologize if this seem like I shouldn't post this question. I have been battling to understand this code since the last 2 weeks and all to no avail.

My main problem is understanding how this delegate works here

```
messageInformer = new MessageInformer(this.Broadcast);
```

I couldn't use debugger to trace the code as VS won't let me do that. I understand the Socket connection, sending and receiving, but I don't get how the delegate work here. From what I noticed, after connecting multiple clients to the server, when a client sends a message to a Server, other clients get the same message as the server

I have an understanding of delegate as a function pointer and I know the basics of delegate.

Please could someone explain to me the flow of how this delegate is used?

Find all codes below:

**Server.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace SimpleChatServer.Communication
{
    class Server
    {
        private Socket serverSock;
        private List<ClientHandler> clientsConnected = new List<ClientHandler>();
        private MessageInformer messageInformer;
        public Server()
        {
            serverSock = new Socket(
                AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream,
                ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Console.WriteLine("Socket created");
            serverSock.Bind(
              new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 8055));
            Console.WriteLine("Binding done");
            serverSock.Listen(5);
            Console.WriteLine("Listening started");
            messageInformer = new MessageInformer(this.Broadcast);
        }

        public void StartAccepting()
        {

            while (true)
            {
                clientsConnected.Add(new ClientHandler(serverSock.Accept(), messageInformer));
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(clientsConnected.Last().StartReceiving));
                thread.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("New Client accepted");
            }
        }


        private void Broadcast(Socket caller, string message)
        {
            foreach (var item in clientsConnected)
            {
                if(!item.ClientSock.Equals(caller))
                item.ClientSock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**ClientHandler.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SimpleChatServer.Communication
{
    class ClientHandler
    {
        private Socket clientSock;
        private MessageInformer informer;

        public Socket ClientSock
        {
            get { return clientSock; }
            //set { clientSock = value; }
        }

        private byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSock, MessageInformer informer)
        {
            this.clientSock = clientSock;
            this.informer = informer;


        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Receive messages from the client
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        public void StartReceiving(object obj)
        {
            int length;
            string name = "";
            string message = "";

            #region  Handle Name
            do
            {
                length = clientSock.Receive(buffer);
                name += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);

            } while (!name.Contains("\r\n"));

            name = name.Substring(0, name.Length - 2);

            clientSock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello " + name + "\r\n"));

            #endregion 

            while (true)
            {
                length = clientSock.Receive(buffer);
                message += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
                if (message.Contains("\r\n"))
                {

                    Console.Write(name + ": " + message);
                    informer(clientSock, name + ": " + message);
                    message = "";

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Delegaters.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SimpleChatServer.Communication
{
  public delegate void  MessageInformer(Socket caller, string message);
}
```

**program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SimpleChatServer.Communication;

namespace SimpleChatServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Server server = new Server();
            server.StartAccepting();
            server.StartAccepting();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you should learn how to use the debugger in a scenario like this. (Start several Studios, one for each client, attach one to server). Additionally you may use TRACE Messages and/or Console.Write*() messages to follow the flow of this code. Yes, socket code **is** convoluted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from top to bottom:

```
public delegate void  MessageInformer(Socket caller, string message);
```

This is the delegate definition, no work is done here yet.

```
messageInformer = new MessageInformer(this.Broadcast);
```

This sets the private variable messageInformer (which is of the MessageInformer delegate type) to a new Value: an instantiated delegate targeting this class' method Broadcast. Which has to have the same Parameters as the delegate type to be appliable as a target for this delegate. Compare these Parameters:

```
public delegate **void**  MessageInformer(**Socket** caller, **string** message);
private **void** Broadcast(**Socket** caller, **string** message)
```

calling `messageInformer(mySocket, myMessage);` would now redirect the call to `Server.Broadcast(mySocket, MyMessage)`, regardless from where this delegate is called, as this delegate is bound to this instance of Server's Broadcast method and not dependant on the context in which it is called.

```
clientsConnected.Add(new ClientHandler(serverSock.Accept(), messageInformer));
```

this line creates a new ClientHandler with a newly connected socket and provides it with the messageInformerDelegate which still points to Server.Broadcast even if it now is given to ClientHandler. The delegate is then saved as `informer` inside the ClientHandler.

```
informer(clientSock, name + ": " + message);
```

This line inside the ClientHandler.StartReceiving Method now calls the Server.BroadCast Method providing it's own socket and the message it received. It could be chaned to `myServer.Broadcast(clientSock, name + ": "+ message);` if you'd own a reference to your server inside your ClientHandler.

the Server.Broadcast method then loops through all Sockets, and forwards the recived message, aber checking if the Socket provided by the delegate call (which is always the calling Clienthandler's socket in this case) would be the socket that this message is forwarded to.